# Is Federer Formula of sample size in experimentation study (t-1)(n-1) ≥ 15 legit?

Tags: references, sample-size, sample

I've seen this formula for sample size determination in experimental studies, which was claimed by Walter Federer, is well-known among Indonesian bio researchers.

The formula is:

$$ (t-1)(n-1) \geq 15$$

However, I have never heard of this before.
The best that I found is [this article](https://ecommons.cornell.edu/server/api/core/bitstreams/3c2e9629-1159-4406-8337-093c464685f9/content), which I can't find the exact formula stated (I could be miss tho).

Does any of you ever heard of this exact formula and have the source to the main article?

Note: I am aware that sample size calculation based on power analysis is robust and prefer that approach as well. But, I would like to confirm the above formula due to its popularity.

Comment: The fact that $n=30$ is enough to rely on the CLT always & everywhere is also "well known", but that doesn't make it true. What is $t$ in this formula?

Comment: A bit of digging in (Indonesian) literature shows that $t$ is the number of treatments, and the reference for this formula appears to be [this book](https://books.google.be/books/about/Experimental_Design.html?id=IqfCugAACAAJ). Confusingly the formula is sometimes also cited as $t(n-1)>15$.

Comment: @PBulls yeah I track the book as well, but haven't seen the exact formula cited. Have you found where the formula shown in the book like in which page?

Comment: I don't see it either. I recall reading a similar argument in a paper (long lost since) that $n=15$ suffices for animal experiments, the reason given that at that point the absolute magnitude of the standard error 'stops decreasing as much'. Another possible line of thinking may be that at 15 degrees of freedom a t distribution is 'sufficiently normal'. Either way I doubt this rule of thumb is any more valid than the one I cited above.

Comment: Interesting. Will look through it more. Thanks for sharing your thoughts